# How do fuel/oxidizer combustion mechanics change when the constituents are supercritical?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, kinetics, combustion

The problem to solve is this: I want to create a heat generator [or heat absorber] that functions at atmospheric pressure to the pressure at the bottom of the sea. It will be used to drive a Stirling engine.

As such, I'm worried that a simple burner with adjustable flow rates won't act predictably at extreme pressures.

Givens:

- 1 atm - 1000 atm ambient pressure
- I can maintain a constant differential pressure between fuel/oxidizer bottles and the reactor
- 1 kW output power (small in scale)
- Nitrous oxide/hydrocarbon (probably propane) constituents [edit: not set in stone]

Will the combustion chemistry work out? Is the reaction so fast that stable combustion is impossible at low flow rates?

I am also reading up on supercritical hydrothermal combustion as an alternate solution. I have contemplated using liquid nitrogen as a heat absorber, but it is appx 1/100 mass-efficient in terms of energy input/output. Alternate solutions that avoid the problem entirely are also welcome. <3

Comment: Pu238 would work well at *any* pressure (short of being at the center of shaped charges), and would not need to be refueled frequently, but it *would* be difficult to get... not even NASA has a steady supply.

Comment: Haha! That may get some eyes on my pet project that I'd rather not attract... That would be an excellent solution, however ;)